# Mark checkbox completed - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of, i'm new to React.

I'm trying to build a todo-list app just for practice.

there's a list of todo items (with a title ,checkbox,
 and a property named 'completed' defaulted to false.)

the logic is simple when the completed property is turned to true to item will get a line-through style.

my problem is:

the problem comes when i mark the first To-do item everything works fine.
then when i go to the second item and try to mark him the app breaks.

```
my code:


class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      todos: [],
      userType: ""
    }
    this.inputEvent = this.inputEvent.bind(this)
    this.submitEvent = this.submitEvent.bind(this)
  }

  checkMark = (id) => {
    this.setState(oldState => {
      const newTodo = oldState.todos.map(x => {
        if (x.id === id) {
          x.completed = !x.completed
          return x
        }
        console.log(newTodo)
        return newTodo
      })
      return {
        todos: newTodo
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: The app breaks in what way?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: How are you calling `checkMark`?

Comment: checkMark is an onChange event

<input onChange={() => this.props.checkMark(this.props.id)} type="checkbox"
                 checked={this.props.completed} />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return `newTodo` in map which is undefined here

Try like

```
  checkMark = (id) => {
    this.setState(oldState => {
      const newTodo = oldState.todos.map(x => {
        if (x.id === id) {
          x.completed = !x.completed
          return x
        }
        return x
      })
      return {
        todos: newTodo
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks that was it :) !

Comment: Btw, is there any other way (more proficient to write this code?), just wondering.